# SignatureDoesNotMatch on gCloud

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I cannot get the upload on a Google Cloud Signed URL to work. I get the same SignatureDoesNotMatch error.

I tried lots of things including:

- deactivating the v4 for the v2
- adding or removing content type
- changing fetch with axios
- using Postman
- try to be a wizard with POST and then PUT and `x-goog-resumable:start`
- change the CORS of my bucket
- increasing the timeout

I just never get the upload to work.

The token creation code:

```
public static String generateV4PutObjectSignedUrl(String objectName) throws StorageException {
    // String projectId = "my-project-id";
    // String bucketName = "my-bucket";
    // String objectName = "my-object";

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // Define Resource
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of("mybucket", objectName)).build();

    // Generate Signed URL
    Map<String, String> extensionHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    extensionHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

    URL url = storage.signUrl(
            blobInfo,
            15,
            TimeUnit.HOURS,
            Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(extensionHeaders),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature()
    );

    String urlS = url.toString();
    System.out.println("Generated PUT signed URL:"+urlS);
    return urlS;
}
```

then the CORS of the bucket:

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600000, "method": ["GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "POST"], "origin": ["LIVE", "http://localhost:8080", "http://0.0.0.0:8080"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "x-goog-resumable"]}]
```

And then my attempts to put:

```
const signedUrl = await fetch("$STORAGE_FUN/" + apkFile.name.replace(" ", "_")).then((res) => res.text());
await axios.put(signedUrl, apkFile);
```

As well as:

```
const put = await fetch(signedUrl, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'},
  body: apkFile
})
```

As well as:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/no-heroes-here.apk?GoogleAccessId=autodeploy@company.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1676643070&Signature=ZYU7CjzWRcKaqjOufUZ%2BkOJA%2FsB1vVpWBZAfpeUKIrmQRHJ6ZgXE7bwmqtaIWwBCbZv%2Fa1naYV3xC2OMqhpZ7ene46ZWS4JH%2FIvVn2U5SMBjYG38SrKqICLfj3l4sN%2BR39ijTxPwP4nWCpvMm39CxtCZAC6n5FovsNterZ7NqByXHP7YXgzOXeiBALabDv%2B%2BnclpVtoJ4K6h%2ByFKyQ6odzT0PTDIvpED4ph%2BIrdptwxraFFpLNL8k0ocAsd1zn9U4cxRrTTFCMzzMaXdhXRfVAtkSl5NW7BosdkRmgGtB%2FA1TEifea%2BnfXyXtbRaW7QG5TA9WxrA3VmHNMWz3At29A%3D%3D' \
-H 'Content-Type:' \
--data-binary '@/somepath/original/noheroeshere/no-heroes-here.apk'
```

And we get a similar error as:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
    <StringToSign>GOOG4-RSA-SHA256
20230216T232500Z
20230216/auto/storage/goog4_request
338a1267c21129d5a991a59881cf42c0112f6cfd5cc067c162e0716adc059d5e</StringToSign>
    <CanonicalRequest>PUT
/mybucket/no-heroes-here.apk
X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&amp;X-Goog-Credential=autodeploy%40company.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20230216%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&amp;X-Goog-Date=20230216T232500Z&amp;X-Goog-Expires=54000&amp;X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost
content-type:application/octet-stream
host:storage.googleapis.com

content-type;host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
</Error>
```

Many questions:

- Do you see an obvious error in my code?
- Is there a way to debug the Signature Error like some logs in the bucket that where we could see what is actually not matching?
- Can it be a permission problem of the service account that I'm using?
- Would the URL be generated if the service account wouldn't work?

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236389/uploading-to-google-cloud-using-a-signed-url) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890062/put-files-to-google-cloud-storage-gcs-via-signed-urls),[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761597/how-to-upload-file-to-google-cloud-bucket-using-signedurl),[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422663/error-with-signed-writable-url-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-mat)

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the “&” is encoded to `&amp;` which make signed URL invalid.